# mark search string dynamically using angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How can I mark my search pattern dynamically in my html?
Example:

[image: SearchExample]

I'm using angular and my html looks like this:

```
<div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="viewmodel.searchString"/>
   <!--Moving over all phrases-->
   <div ng-repeat="phrase in viewmodel.Phrases">
        {{phrase.title}}            
   </div>
</div>
```

I want the string matching pattern will be mark on every change in search string.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Angular UI is a great choice. You can also do it with filter like: http://embed.plnkr.co/XbCsxmfrgmdtOAeBZPUp/preview

The essence is as commented by @Hylianpuffball, dynamically create styled 'span' tags for the matches.

```
.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
  return function(text, phrase) {
    if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
      '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
  }
})
```

And use it like:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search.title"
    ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search.title">
</li>
```

Comment: great solutions, both of them. i went for the separate filter due to modularity :)

Comment: what if initial text or search phrase contain html in them?

Comment: I believe it still works with HTML text, but for the search phrase you will need to escape the special characters so that the RegExp is valid. If that's the case, you might want to switch to a more sophisticated text matching "backend" such as [Lunr](http://lunrjs.com/) instead of plain RegExp.

Comment: I am not getting the class if i implement the example as given in the plukr code :(

Answer (score 1):

Just in case that someone (like me a moment ago) needs this for angular2:

highlight-pipe.ts:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'highlightPipe'})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform{

  transform(text:string, filter:string) : any{
    if(filter){
      text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+filter+')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

at top of file:

```
import {HighlightPipe} from './highlight-pipe';
```

in template where '*yourText*' is the original text and '*filter*' is the part you want to highlight:

```
<div [innerHTML]="yourText | highlightPipe: filter"/>
```

in component:

```
pipes: [HighlightPipe]
```

EDIT:
I updated it for RC 4
and created a plunker for testing:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SeNsuwFUUqZIHllP9nT0?p=preview

Comment: How do you define the highlighted css class? 
I have a similar filter that I use in a table row populated by *ngFor.
The result I get is indeed a span with the highlight class but the style cannot be applied because the css gets modified to end with  [_ngcontent-hnu-2], and the browser obviously can't find my span this way. Do you have any workaround for this? At the moment, only inline style="font-weight:bold" works because I can't use css classes this way which is pretty sad :/

Comment: I defined a regular css file with a .highlighted{} class which is referenced in the index.html, the classes did not get changed. What is modifying your css class?

Comment: I made a plunker for you to see my implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/SeNsuwFUUqZIHllP9nT0?p=preview

Comment: @BjörnKechel, never mind! I've just had to replace the ```pipes:[]```´ from ```@Component``` to @NgModule

Answer (score 0):

Try [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.com/)

They have a highlight directive. You can use it as a reference to make your own (or just use it directly).

Comment: There's no 'simple' way to do this in core angular... though you could argue it is 'simple' to write your own directive that does it.  Either way, you need a custom directive that can search through its contents and dynamically create styled spans based on a match.  I would also recommend using an existing one if possible, like Angular UI, to avoid some headache.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @tungd's answer but valid for multiple search terms.

```
.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
  return function(text, phrase) {
    if (phrase){
        phrases = phrase.split(" ");
        for(i=0;i<phrases.length;i++)
            text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrases[i]+')', 'gi'),'~~~~~$1%%%%%')

        text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+'~~~~~'+')', 'gi'),'<span class="bold greenTxt">');
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+'%%%%%'+')', 'gi'),'</span>')      
    } 
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
  }
});
```

PS: One can always limit the input to be in non-special chars for this to be 100% bullet-proof.