# Change font color of first occurrence of a letter

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to find a way to change the font color of the **first occurrence** of a letter in a div. So for example if the String was 'The text' and I wanted to change the color of 'e' yellow. Then only the **first e** would be affected. 'Th**e** text' This is what I have to far:

```
<div class="translation-esan-div">
  {{$scope.someValue}}
</div>
```

When I access this element using:

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("translation-esan-div"))
```

the text() value returned is **{{$scope.someValue}}** and not the angular evaluated text.

The text in $scope.someValue could be anything. I would already have a predefined css class specifying the color.  The letter to change would be passed into the accompanying controller. How would I go about just changing the color of a specific letter?

Comment: How about a custom filter like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597286/mark-search-string-dynamically-using-angular-js#answer-20602723) answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try using JavaScript to pull the contents of a desired element out, do some plain old string handling, and push 2 nested `<span>`s back into the original container, with the inner one replacing the letter and applying the style by assigning the `"translation-esan-div"` class to the inner `<span>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution via [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

```js
angular.module('app',['ngSanitize']).controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {    
    $scope.process = function(letter, text){
        if(letter && text){
            var index = text.indexOf(letter);
            var result = '';
            if(index != -1){
              for(var i = 0 ; i < index; i++)
                result += text[i];
              result += '<span class="yellow">' + text.substr(index, letter.length) + '</span>';
              for(var i = index + letter.length ; i < text.length; i++)
                result += text[i];
              return result;
            }         
        }
        return text;
    }
}]);
```

```css
.yellow {
    color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyController">
   letter:
   <input ng-init='letter="e"' ng-model='letter' type='text'/>
   <br>
   text:
   <input ng-init='someValue="The text"' ng-model='someValue' type='text'/>
   <p ng-bind-html="process(letter, someValue)"></p>
</div>
```